# Footer not coming down with the use of flex it is coming on the right side

Tags: css, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR4rK.png)

Here is App.js code in react

```
// App.js
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import IPOWebsite from './components/IPOWebsite'
import IPOCalculator from './components/IPOCalculator'
import Calculator from './components/Calculator'
import Navbar from './components/NavBar'
import Footer from './components/Footer'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div id='root'>
        <div className='IPOCalculator'>
          <IPOCalculator />
          <u>
            <h4>Calculator for any other calculation:</h4>
          </u>
          <Calculator />
        </div>
        <div className='IPOWebsite'>
          <IPOWebsite />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer className='Footer' />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here is App.css code

```
/* App.css */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.IPOCalculator {
  flex: 0.5; 
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.IPOWebsite {
  flex: 0.5; 
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.Footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  order: 999;
  display: flex;
}
```

Footer.js is not having any style as such that will impact

Still here's the Footer.js code

```
import React from 'react'

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#333',
        color: 'white',
        padding: '2rem',
        textAlign: 'center',
        marginTop: '2rem', // Add margin at the top to separate from the content
      }}
    >
      <div>
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <p>Email: info@breakoutpickr.com</p>
        <p>Phone: +1 (555) 123-4567</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Quick Links</h2>
        <ul style={{ listStyleType: 'none', padding: 0 }}>
          <li>
            <a
              href='/policy'
              style={{
                color: 'white',
                textDecoration: 'none',
                margin: '0.5rem',
              }}
            >
              Privacy Policy
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a
              href='/terms'
              style={{
                color: 'white',
                textDecoration: 'none',
                margin: '0.5rem',
              }}
            >
              Terms of Service
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Subscribe to Our Newsletter</h2>
        <form
          style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <input
            type='email'
            placeholder='Your Email'
            style={{ margin: '0.5rem', padding: '0.5rem', borderRadius: '5px' }}
          />
          <button
            type='submit'
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#4CAF50',
              color: 'white',
              padding: '0.5rem 1rem',
              borderRadius: '5px',
              border: 'none',
              cursor: 'pointer',
            }}
          >
            Subscribe
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </footer>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

I tried mutilple times but could not get this simple thing done
I tried by giving position as fixed and abosolute, display as flex, order as a high value

Comment: `display: flex` aligns content horizontally. Please add a `flex-direction: column` to your `body` tag and verify whether the changes are what you are looking for.

Comment: @AbhayVAshokan
Yes I tried that but then but I want IPOCalculator and IPOWebsite next to each other by taking 50% of the width
they are coming below each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved by using flex direction

```js
// App.js
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import IPOWebsite from './components/IPOWebsite'
import IPOCalculator from './components/IPOCalculator'
import Calculator from './components/Calculator'
import Navbar from './components/NavBar'
import Footer from './components/Footer'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div id='root' className='app-container'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='IPOCalculator'>
            <IPOCalculator />
            <u>
              <h4>Calculator for any other calculation:</h4>
            </u>
            <Calculator />
          </div>
          <div className='IPOWebsite'>
            <IPOWebsite />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer className='Footer' />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

```css
#root {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```